# Objects are not valid as a React child with state while rendering error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic with React I am getting this error:

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {...}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

The function getTimes should be returning a JSON object with key and value eg. {tmp1: '1:05', tmp2: '2:05'} but I am getting an error when trying to render, eventhough in console.log i can see the result.

```
export const getTimes = (date: Date) => {
 const API_URL = '...'
    return axios({
      url: API_URL,
      method: 'get'
    }).then(response => {     
      return response.data.data.timings;
    })
}
```

whereas in the tsx file where I do the rendering

```
const theTimes = () =>{
const [state, setState] = useState({ isLoading: true, collection: null });

useIonViewWillEnter(()=>{
    getTimes(new Date()).then(res=>{
        setState({ isLoading: false, collection: res });
    })
})

    console.log(state.collection);


return <IonCard>{state.collection}</IonCard>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `state.collection` is an object (`{tmp1: '1:05', tmp2: '2:05'}`). React doesn't know how to handle this, or what to do, so it's throwing an error.

It depends on what you're trying to render, but you likely want to render each of the individual object properties.

For example:

```
  return <IonCard>{state.collection.tmp1} {state.collection.tmp2}</IonCard>
```

Comment: I tried it, I get another error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tmp1' of null, eventhough it is not null...

Comment: It's likely `null` on initial render, while the data is still being fetched. You will need to wait until the data has been loaded. You could do this with another value in state that starts as `loading: true` and is set to false. Or, you can check if the data is `null` before rendering. For example: `<IonCard>{state.collection ? state.collection.tmp1 : "loading..."}</IonCard >`

Answer (score 0):

`<IonCard>{state.collection}</IonCard>`
here is the problem.

Solution

1. if you want to print the data your need to use like this

```
Object.keys(state.collection).map((key, index) => {

  return <IonCard>{state.collection[key]}</IonCard>
})
```

1. If you want to pass the value to the IonCard use like this

```
return <IonCard myCollection={state.collection}/>
```

in IonCard

```
const IonCard = ({myCollection}) => {
 // do what you want to do with myCollection
}
```